# JOptionPane with images on the buttons?

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

How do you create a JOptionPane with images on the buttons in addition to their labels? For example, if I wanted a checkmark on the OK button and an x icon on the cancel button? Is this possible without creating the entire dialog from scratch as a JFrame/JPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a slightly messier looking solution on [java 2 schools](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingComponentstotheButtonAreaUsingJOptionPanewithaJButtoncontainingatextlabelandanicon.htm) that appears to actually work and respond to the button clicks through and action listener:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
    optionPane.setMessage("I got an icon and a text label");
    optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon("yourFile.gif");
    JButton jButton = getButton(optionPane, "OK", icon);
    optionPane.setOptions(new Object[] { jButton });
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(frame, "Icon/Text Button");
    dialog.setVisible(true);

  }

  public static JButton getButton(final JOptionPane optionPane, String text, Icon icon) {
    final JButton button = new JButton(text, icon);
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // Return current text label, instead of argument to method
        optionPane.setValue(button.getText());
        System.out.println(button.getText());
      }
    };
    button.addActionListener(actionListener);
    return button;
  }
```

Comment: Once you start to customize `JOptionPane` instances, it becomes messy, as you have discovered.  Often it is better to side-step it and use a `JDialog`. +1 for finding a solution, though also look into the `Action` API in place of an `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 5):

`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` has a parameter `options` which is an array of `Component`s.
You could pass it an array of custom buttons:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog( parent, question, title,
   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE
   new Component[]{ new JButton("OK", myIcon), 
                    new JButton("cancel", myOtherIcon) 
                  }
 );
```

from the documentation of `JOptionPane`:

> options - an array of objects indicating the possible choices the user
>   can make; if the objects are components, they are rendered properly;

Alternatively you can subclass `JOptionPane`, and change the components and their layout directly.

Comment: For the most part this seems to be on the right track to the solution, however, it's not a fully working for me. It looks like there are a couple more parameters I have to specify (maybe not all java versions are the same? I'm using Java 7), which I've added nulls for, however, nothing happens when you press OK or Cancel. Do custom buttons require action listeners to trigger the "ok" action?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solved with this action listener:

```
    JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Container parent = ok.getParent();
            while (parent != null && !(parent instanceof JDialog)) {
                parent = parent.getParent();
            }
            parent.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```